# Python Websocket wait for variable change

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I have a class that contains a websocket-client WebSocketApp, that is started in a thread.
The websocket connection recieves messages and sets some class variables accordingly.
One example is the login:
A login message is sent, and after a while the `on_message` function recieves a successfull login message. When the function catches this message a `self.logged_in` variable is set to true.
Currently I'm "waiting" for the variable to become true using a busy wait, which is obviously not very good.

```
while websocket.logged_in:
    pass
```

What I need is something like this

```
wait(websocket.logged_in=True, timeout=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice solution using [synchronized Queues](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#simplequeue-objects)
You just need to call `queue.put(var)` in your thread where the message arrives.
In the main you call `queue.get()` which will wait until an element shows up in the queue.
In my case I will probably use multiple queues with just one element for different responses that I'm going to get